# Question of the Week #40

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post #39 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any questions that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: I think this is a candidate   
http://superuser.com/questions/459249/what-am-i-looking-for-in-ram